# How to unwrap all li from ul on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably a dummy question. I am trying to export the contents of a unordered list into a text area and remove the list item on export. I have achieved it at some degree but it only brings in the first list item.
How can I export all the  li's?

HTML :

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <button id="exportBtn">Export</button>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="structure">
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something else</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <textarea id="exportTxt" contenteditable style=""></textarea> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script :

```
$(function() {
  $( "#exportBtn" ).click(function() {
    var htmlString = $('.structure li').html();

    $('textarea#exportTxt').html(htmlString).parent().is( 'li' ).htmlString.unwrap();
    $('textarea#exportTxt').addClass('slideIn');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML that forms the list and the expected output that would fill the textarea.

Comment: Also what do you mean by export?

Comment: I have amended the question. By export I mean get the html from the ul and add it in text area as code removing the li.

Comment: So what goes into the textarea is `SomethingSomething else`?

Comment: Yes exactly. But I need it in text. The user eventually will copy and paste this text area. I hope this makes sense. Thank you all.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kd4Dx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[View working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd4Dx/1/)**

So you want it to read `SomethingSomething else`.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#exportBtn" ).click(function() {
      var html = ''; // start with empty
      $('.structure li').each(function(){
          html += $(this).html(); // append the html from each li
          $(this).remove(); // remove the li
      });
      $('#exportTxt').val(html); // set it in the textarea
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle with a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/PucV2/
Hope this is what you wanted.

js:

```
  $( "#exportBtn" ).on('click', function() {
      $('.structure li').each(function(){
          var txt = $('#exportTxt').text();
          $('#exportTxt').empty();
          $('#exportTxt').text(txt + ' ' + $(this).text());
          $(this).remove();
      });
  });
```

html:

```
<ul class="structure">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<button id="exportBtn">Export</button>
<textarea id="exportTxt"></textarea>
```

Comment: That fills it with `.text()`. OP specifically said HTML

Comment: Why `.empty()` just to then set `.text()` and if you must do that why are those functions chained? Three lines and three lookups to do one thing. **jQuery's motto "Write less do more"**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**js**

```
$("#exportBtn").click(function() {
    var list="";
    $(".structure").children().each(function(){
        list +=$(this).html() + " ";
    });
    $('textarea#exportTxt').val(list);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eJaJ/12/)